# Help identifying this viney jade like succulent

Tags: identification, houseplants, indoors, succulents

I purchased this one about a year ago from a garage sale and has tripled in size. It seems to be a jade like succulent that is viney.

Any help is appreciated.

[image: plant to identify]

Comment: How big are the leaves? If they're fairly small, it may be purslane. Jade plants have much larger leaves than purslane, but they're usually thicker than what you have from those we've had.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Trailing Jade (Kleinia petraea)

Comment: Can you add more details about your identification?  What makes you think this a Kleinia?  A picture or reference would help everyone.

Comment: I agree, this is most likely a correct identification, I will just leave it open for the full 24 hours prior to accepting.